# Impose Height x Length x Width Input field format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, mask

I do have in my *Angular* project an input field which should **obey** the following format:

> Width**x**Height**x**Length, where each value has 2 digits after the decimal point.

I tried to apply some masks, like [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask):

```
     <input matInput maxlength="14" formControlName="dimensions" name="dimensions" 
            mask="0*.00x0*.00x0*.00" [specialCharacters]="['x', '.']"/>
```

But i do have issues when it comes to variable number values length or editing  already set values( input cannot be edited).

Does anyone know any other mask approaches or other solutions?